# Goodman furnace triggering pressure switch error after running for 20+ minutes

Tags: hvac, furnace

My inducer motor bearing was making a ton of noise and likely about to go out so I replaced it. After installing the new inducer motor my furnace will run for 20 to 30 minutes and then throw a pressure switch stuck open error. I tested the pressure switch and it seemed fine; however, since they are relatively inexpensive I replaced it to be sure. The furnace is still throwing the pressure switch error. Everything I've read indicates if there is a problem with the inducer motor or how much air it's moving and/or the pressure switch is actually faulty the furnace will not turn on at all. I haven't been able to find any info where the furnace will run for a significant amount of time and then throw the error. Could it be the board?

Note: Before replacing the inducer motor the furnace ran without issue...it was just really loud.

Comment: Have you tried putting the old motor back in to see if normal (but loud) function resumes?

Comment: Good question. I have not. I don't remember off hand if I kept the old motor. If I did I will definitely try that...

Comment: Re-seat the wiring harness. Perhaps inducer is still running when it's checking to see that every thing is off between cycles. So like, in a half hour it trips on over heat and tries to start a new cycle but inducer is running so it 'looks' stuck open.

Comment: 30 min is a pretty long call for heat. Does it trip out w/o the filter in place and the door off the chamber? (give it as much air as possible) On some units an overheat will leave the inducer running, and the first 3(?) overheats won't throw an error.

Comment: We drop our house down pretty cool at night and it can take 30 mins to 1 1/2 hours to heat to daytime temp. The furnace turns on and we get heat for the 20 to 30 mins it will run and then it just throws the pressure switch error. I'll try re-seating the harness. Thanks.

Comment: Check the blower RPMs, a slight increase in speed will cause a increase in current, pressure and air volume.  The Horsepower will increase by the cube of the speed ratio and so does the current. If you have an adjustable pulley drive slow it down just a little bit and the problem should go away. The best thing you can do to eliminate the motor problem is measure its current and be sure it is within nameplate rating.

Comment: @Gil, that's an interesting approach. I can see how increased airflow from the blower could reduce the vacuum created by the inducer. I'll check that out today. I was having an issue using air filters with to high of a Merv rating (and consequently too low air flow). The HVAC tech left me some very low Merv rating filters that I started using just before changing the inducer. I wonder if using a slightly lower air flow filter would help...

Comment: I doubt it is the board. Because the pressure switch started opening after motor replacement, I would start with @FreeMan’s suggestion of reinstalling the old motor to begin deductively troubleshooting. If that’s not possible, is inducer still running when the pressure switch opens? If it is, then perhaps interfaces/seals were compromised during motor replacement and are expanding as furnace heats up. If inducer is not running after 30 minutes, then I can’t think of any reason why motor would give out except that it’s faulty.

Comment: *I wonder if using a slightly lower air flow filter would help* - that's what I said. Take the filter *totally* out. Take the door *off* and put a magnet on the switch. Run it for 2 hours straight, and ideally all the way into the next startup sequence. - does it quit on you?

Comment: @DoctorYes, I understand what you're saying about the inducer vacuum being independent of air flow from the blower. I suppose my last thing to check would be the gasket on the inducer motor. The behavior definitely happens more quickly when the furnace has been running for a while, so maybe the inducer gasket is just borked enough to lose seal when it gets too hot.

Comment: @Mazura, I will try to run it without the filter next time I get the chance to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I would add below as a comment, but I don’t have enough reputation points to do so. If moderator, such as @BMitch, would move this to comments I think this will help OP, and would appreciate it.

Unless I’m missing something, looking for air flow problems related to the blower motor is a waste of time. The inducer air circuit should be independent of the blower air circuit (unless the heat exchanger is compromised in which case you have a much bigger problem and this should trigger a flame rollout or other trouble code).

Any increased (or decreased) airflow from the blower should have zero effect on the vacuum created by the inducer.